# How to fix text scroll over image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build some simple layout with image on top and text below it.

When ever I scroll the text, the text scrolls up and covers the image.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Tax'),
    ),
    body: Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      color: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _getBackGround(),
          _imglo(),
          _getContent(),
        ],
      ),
Widget _getContent(){
  return ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 272.0, 0.0, 32.0),
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(

        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("ssssssss", style: headerTextStyle),
            Separator(),
            Text("ssss", style: 
regulatTextStyle,textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,),
Text("sss", style: regulatTextStyle,textDirection: 
TextDirection.rtl,)
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

What can I do to make the text not overlap the image?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Can you provide your build method and/or a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I edited the question and added the code of the build method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text scrolls over the image because you're using a [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), which is used for overlaying elements on top of each other. For what you want to achieve, it looks like you don't need a `Stack` at all, you need a decorated [`Container`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and a [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html).

Assuming your background is an image (hence the use of a `Stack` in your question), your build method could look something like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container( // An empty widget we can decorate.
        decoration: new BoxDecoration( // We want to decorate it with an...
          image: new DecorationImage( // ...image!
            image: new NetworkImage("https://via.placeholder.com/800"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover, // Make the image cover all space in the container.
          ),
        ),
        child: Column( // Arranges children vertically on the screen, no scrolling.
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/300"), // `_imglo` goes here.
            Expanded( // Make the ListView fill up all remaining column space.
              child: ListView.builder(
                // Example ListView. Your `_getContent()` goes here.
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                      title: const Text("Example"),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        index.toString(),
                      ),
                    ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Alternatively, if color is all you want for your background, the `Scaffold` widget has a `backgroundColor` property:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: ...
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but somehow only the first part worked, and the part of the column didn't work well...at first the column didn't work at all, I had  "RenderBox was not laid out" so i wrap my listView at _myContent with expanded widget.                                                                                                                         and now the parts of "_imglo" and the image works fine, but  _myContent and the background color don't work

Comment: I've updated my answer code to be a working example. You were right to add the `Expanded` widget. If color is all you need then you don't need to fiddle about with the top-level `Container` widget, you can just set the background color on the scaffold.

Comment: First - You were very helpful , you made me understand where my mistake was.
I forgot to mention one thing - I needed the stack because the Imglo should cover the backround image. My mistake.
I added the solution that I finally found, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tax'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        color: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
           Stack(
              children: <Widget>[_getBackGround(), imglo()],
            ),
            Container(
              child: _getContent(),
           )
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
 }
```